# why source() function works while insertSource() gave me error to insert a specific function in R?

Tags: r, function

I have a bunch of question saved in funcs.r file. While I have no issue to source the whole file, it gave me the following error while I only tried to insert one specific function from that file. Here is my codes and errors

```r
source("./funcs.r")
insertSource("funcs.r",functions = "ColorPalette")

Error in .guessPackageName(env) :
none of the objects in the source code could be found: need to attach or specify the package
3.
stop("none of the objects in the source code could be found: need to attach or specify the package")
2.
.guessPackageName(env)
1.
insertSource("./funcs.r",
functions = "ColorPalette")
```

I tried load all functions using source(), and it works with no errors.

Why does insertSource() give me this error? What should I do?

Comment: From [`?insertSource`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/methods/html/evalSource.html): *"Definitions of functions and/or methods from a source file are inserted into a package ..."*. The use of `insertSource` is intended for package development, not for attempting to source portions of a file (which would be useful nonetheless). I don't know of an easy way to source only a portion of a non-package file.